# Cannot get screen captures faster than one per 17 ms

Tags: java, kotlin, screenshot, screen-recording

I am trying to make trigger, using Kotlin, which can work faster than one image per 17 ms. But it cant give me that time despite all my solutions

I tried to use
1) Robot().createScreenCapture()
2) FFMpegGrabber
3) multithreaded Robot
4) multiple instances of my programm.
But it can't give me time faster than 17 ms, when i launch 4 programms, they all work with 68 ms each, which is (17 * 4), how to fix that problem? Maybe there is some low-level framework for kotlin/java which can do that?

Comment: Why do you need this to be so quickly? What is "trigger"? Assuming your screen refresh rate is 60Hz, your screen would refresh every ~17ms. It is not meaningful to get screenshots any more quickly than that - the screen wouldn't have updated.

Comment: For example of "trigger" i want to autoclick on moving red circle, which is under my mouse cursor, when it appears at cursor location, but my programm can not get in time and clicks to empty spot